# Easy- Json and PHP decode

Tags: php, json

I'm working with an API from underground weather. I'm trying to put some values into my website on localhost. I include a lot of values without problem. Like:

> Temperature: 30°F
>
> Wind: Fast

Here is the json of those values:

[image]

```
"current_observation": {
        "image": {
        "url":"http://icons-ak.wxug.com/graphics/wu2/logo_130x80.png",
        "title":"Weather Underground",
        "link":"http://www.wunderground.com"
        },
        "display_location": {
        "full":"Buenos Aires, Argentina",
        "city":"Buenos Aires",
        "state":"",
        "state_name":"Argentina",
        "country":"AG",
        "country_iso3166":"AR",
        "zip":"00000",
        "magic":"1",
        "wmo":"87582",
        "latitude":"-34.56999969",
        "longitude":"-58.41999817",
        "elevation":"6.00000000"
        },
        "observation_location": {
        "full":"Palermo, Buenos Aires, Ciudad Autónoma de Buenos Aires",
        "city":"Palermo, Buenos Aires",
        "state":"Ciudad Autónoma de Buenos Aires",
        "country":"Argentina",
        "country_iso3166":"AR",
        "latitude":"-34.595318",
        "longitude":"-58.419781",
        "elevation":"124 ft"
        },
        "estimated": {
        },
        "station_id":"IBUENOSA157",
        "observation_time":"Last Updated on April 26, 7:52 PM ART",
        "observation_time_rfc822":"Sat, 26 Apr 2014 19:52:51 -0300",
        "observation_epoch":"1398552771",
        "local_time_rfc822":"Sat, 26 Apr 2014 19:52:52 -0300",
        "local_epoch":"1398552772",
        "local_tz_short":"ART",
        "local_tz_long":"America/Buenos_Aires",
        "local_tz_offset":"-0300",
        "weather":"Clear",
        "temperature_string":"65.8 F (18.8 C)",
        "temp_f":65.8,
        "temp_c":18.8,
        "relative_humidity":"63%",
```

and in the index php file:

```
<?php
$json_string = file_get_contents("http://api.wunderground.com/api/f84c5a4cd54b3216/geolookup/alerts/astronomy/almanac/conditions/forecast/hourly/q/autoip.json");
$parsed_json = json_decode($json_string);
$temp_c = $parsed_json->{'current_observation'}->{'temp_c'};
echo "{$'temp_c'};
```

That displays the temperature. The temperature in the json code is in: `Current_observation` and then the value `temp_c`.

The problem is that I want to echo the forecast, and the forecast is in a different location  than the `temp_c`.

For example. I want to echo the current conditions, that is here:

[image]

The problem is, that is in:

`{'forecast'}->{'simpleforecast'}->{'forecastday'}` and then there is a zero for the current day, a 1 for the next day, a 2 for the following day, and a 3 for the next to the next day.

When I try to do that in php:

```
{'forecast'}->{'simpleforecast'}->{'forecastday'}->{'0'}->{'conditions'};
```

It does not show anything. How I can go into a value json when in the array there is a 0?

PD: for 0, there is one condition, for 1 (that is next day) there is other condition, and like that the others day. Thanks

Comment: Ok, how are you storing this forecast data? Is it in a variable yet? Without code, "It does not show anything" isn't very helpful.

Comment: the problem is, i cant get the data. For example, i do: $forecastcondition = $parsed_json->{'forecast'}->{'simpleforecast'}->{'forecastday'}->{'0'}->{'conditions'}; and nothing

Comment: from the code you just put in your comment, it appears to me like you're using the same variable and I can't help but think you're attempting to access the same JSON data. If it is, in fact, the same as you have posted above in your question, there is no 'simpleforecast' object to access. Show us how you're accessing the **new** JSON information.

Comment: http://k42.kn3.net/DAF461398.png

Comment: **Not** the acutal JSON data, how are you **accessing** it in your PHP script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were really close but `{'0'}` means there is an object with the key `0`, while you really wanted to access the first index of `forecastday`

```
var_dump($parsed_json->{'forecast'}->{'simpleforecast'}->{'forecastday'}[0]->conditions);
```

Comment: THANKS! THATS WAS I DONE BAD

Answer (score 2):

For me it just works fine, I just tested your code, I just modified it a little bit:

```
<?php
$json_string = file_get_contents("http://api.wunderground.com/api/f84c5a4cd54b3216/geolookup/alerts/astronomy/almanac/conditions/forecast/hourly/q/autoip.json");
$parsed_json = json_decode($json_string, true);

$desired_forecast = $parsed_json['forecast']['simpleforecast']['forecastday'][0]['conditions'];

echo '<pre>';
print_r($desired_forecast); // Thunderstorm
echo '</pre>';
```

It is accessible.

Comment: I was about to answer exactly the same thing! I.e. add the second parameter of `true` to `json_decode()` so you get back an associative array, instead of objects. Then just use simple square brackets to get out what you need (including `[0]`, with no quotes, to get first item in an array).

Comment: thanks! WORKS PERFECTLY, THE PROBLEM WAS Y FORGOT TO DELETE THE ' ON THE 0.